# Spring Tools Suite 4 download fails with Eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Photon and Windows 10 and trying to download the STS version 4 from the marketplace (or by drag and drop) the installation constantly stalls at 49 percent and I get this error:

[image: Eclipse install error message]

Any tips or help appreciated!

Comment: Please include the error message as text instead of an image in your question. Is it possible to manually download the JARs mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a typical network or repository caching issue. I would recommend to go to the `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Updtae Sites`, select the one that is used and press `reload`. That refreshes the internal repository caches. Then try again the install. You could also delete all those STS-related update sites from that preference and try again the marketplace entry. That should solve the issue.

Reference: [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4)